# Replace special characters in a dataframe with the normal variant dataframe is empty

Tags: r

I'm new to R and want to replace all the special characters in my dataframe.

i've looked it up via stack and it partially works. All the special characters are replaced with there normal counterparts example `ä --> a` . The problem i'm encountering is that the dataframe doesn't exist anymore.

**funtion to replace**

```
plain_text = function(x) {
  old1 <- "šžþàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüý"
  new1 <- "szyaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuy"
  x = apply(x,2,function(x) gsub(old1,new1,x))
}
```

**R script**

```
df1 = plain_text(df)
```

**dataframe**

```
V1
1 c("Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar")
2 c("Foo","Bar","Foo","Bar")
3 c("fixed","fixed","not fixed","fixed")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `apply`, it can be (and is here) destructive to a `data.frame`. In this case, you can use `chartr`. I caution that your function should take into considering if a column is `character` or not (since fixing letters on a numeric column breaks it).

```r
plain_text = function(x) {
  old1 <- "šžþàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüý"
  new1 <- "szyaaaaaaceeeeiiiidnooooouuuuy"
  ischr <- sapply(x, is.character)
  x[ischr] <- lapply(x[ischr], chartr, old = old1, new = new1)
  x
}
```

The [`chartr`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/chartr.html) function translates from one set of characters to another (so that `old=` and `new=` must be strings with the same number of characters). It is analogous to the shell command [`tr`](https://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/tr1.html).

The reason `apply` is bad is that it converts its arguments to a `matrix` before doing anything. If the frame is all `character`, then this does not destroy any data, but it does lose the `data.frame` structure (perhaps easily re-applied with `as.data.frame`). A more idiomatic way for a frame is to `lapply` over its columns (analogous to `MARGIN=2` for `apply`), and it returns a `list`. (A `data.frame` is effectively just a special-case `list`.) If we just ran `lapply(x, ...)` and reassigned it to `x`, then `x` would now be a list; however, by reassigning to specific columns with `x[ischr]<-` (or all columns using `x[]<-`, not shown here), then `x` is still a frame albeit with those columns changed.

Lastly, `gsub` is not used well there because it is looking for the entire string `"šžþàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðñòóôõöùúûüý"`, not just one of its characters. What this job needs (I believe) is a one-by-one look at the characters, and replace them in-kind.

Comment: thank for this detailed explanation. it worked. I've to note the i forgot to mention that the dataframe was entirely made out of strings no numeric values. but it is good to keep this in mind.

Comment: Safer programming. It's always `character` until it isn't :-) Running that test and subsetting into `lapply` is very little overhead, and I suggest well worth it to prevent introducing a significant bug into any data pipeline. Glad it works.